# Debugging stuff that lives in lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Normally, in a rails app, writing the `puts` or `Rails.logger` outputs data to the console. However, for some reason, when you step in to code that lives in `lib`, anything written to those streams is "swallowed" or something -- that is, it doesn't end up on `stdout`! Any strategies for debugging this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You may be a victim of `ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger`, which buffers the log output and flushes it when asked to. Because you're not asking it to do it in your `lib` files (hint: it automatically does it in controllers / models / whatever is used in a request), then it simply won't.

What you need to do is tell it you want to do it wherever you need it:

```
Rails.logger.auto_flushing = true
```

Then you can call the other `Rails.logger` methods to your heart's content.

Comment: I think this is the case! I will give this a try and see what happens I was considering moving to Log4r...

Answer (score 0):

Logger works correctly in classes in lib folder. All lib/* content is not reloaded automatically though, so make sure you restarted your server after you inserted the Rails.logger line.